# Parent-child node relationship without using taxonomy?

Tags: nodes, navigation

I'd like to be able to offer sub-site maintainer's the ability to create their own sections of content. I can use a hierarchical taxonomy tree to force multiple levels of content to be classified at different depths of the site. However, I'd rather not be on the hook for revising custom nested term lists for each maintainer.

Is there an easy way to allow publishers to create parent node <-> child node relationships without relying on taxonomy revisions?

I'm using Drupal 7 and Node Hierarchy is unfortunately not yet out of development for D7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.

You create two content types: Parent and Child.

in Child content type, add an mandatory "Entity Reference" field that reference to a Parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using book module which comes with drupal core. you can checkout the documentation provided [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book).

> A book is a set of pages tied together in a hierarchical sequence,
>   perhaps with chapters, sections, subsections, and so on. You can use
>   books for manuals, site resource guides, Frequently Asked Questions
>   (FAQs), or whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this of a simple project management system.
I have one content type - Project/Task which has a node reference that I call Parent Task that is NOT required.

I have a simple module that adds in a task level if this field is filled out and then indent this.  Let me know if you want more details.